# Find Superscript and Subscript in ms word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to convert word files to html for insert to database and I can't find **subscript** and **superscript**.
How can I find these from Microsot Word file?

Comment: obj.Find.Font.Subscript && obj.Find.Font.Superscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution for my question:

```
 if (range.Font.Subscript > 0 || range.Font.Superscript > 0)
 {
      foreach (var subItem in range.Words)
      {
           var supTempRange = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range;
           supTempRange.Find.ClearFormatting();
           supTempRange.Find.Format = true;
           supTempRange.Find.Font.Superscript = 1;

           while (supTempRange.Find.Execute())
           {
              MessageBox.Show(supTempRange.Text);
           }

          var subTempRange = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range; 
          subTempRange.Find.ClearFormatting();
          subTempRange.Find.Format = true;
          subTempRange.Find.Font.Subscript = 1;

          while (subTempRange.Find.Execute())
          {
              MessageBox.Show(subTempRange.Text);
          }
  }}
```